# Is it possible to automatically create a chat room for questions that remain unanswered which have more than say x votes and y time has elapsed?

Tags: feature-request

I say this because I notice some of these questions are not really answerable at the moment, yet they are worthy of discussion. It seems to me creating a chat room would allow for a more relaxed atmosphere where various "theories" can be pondered upon.

I have no clue what x and y are.

---

From Casey's answer below, I forked one of the queries to perform this rough draft:

```
-- Questions with high score and high viewcount yet unanswered
-- Unanswered means any question that has not been formally accepted (there could be answers). 
select top 500 Id as [Post Link], Score, ViewCount from Posts 
where Score > 10 and ViewCount > 100 and ParentId is null and AcceptedAnswerId is null
order by ViewCount desc
```

Try it here:
http://data.stackexchange.com/earthscience/query/edit/255433

There are probably better ways to do this. Let me know what you think.

---

Updated query with min comments

http://data.stackexchange.com/earthscience/query/edit/256871

These parameters show a few potential candidates.

> daysold = 30
>
> minscore = -5 (this should be low, right now it does not matter but in
>   the future it may)
>
> mincomments = 3

Comment: related, but not a dupe http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/331/tackling-the-unanswered-list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to do this would be to create a search or a data.stackexchange.com query to find all questions you are interested in. Once you have a list you could coordinate it in a meta post (updating as necessary). Finally you can create a chatroom to discuss them. You could link to it in your meta post and in comments to your target questions.

[Here is an example data query](http://data.stackexchange.com/earthscience/query/edit/255583) I put together.  This particular query lets you interactively enter how many days old you want and what the minimum question score is (your x and y) that you enter into the text boxes under the query.  You can play with the numbers and see how the results change.  My query selects all questions with score > ##minscore##, older than ##daysold##, with no accepted answers, not closed, and with no answers with score > 2.  This additional constraint on answers can be tuned to eliminate questions where the asker never came back to accept a good answer.

Comment: @IsopycnalOscillation I added a data query to my answer you can take a look at.  Also, let me suggest "Irresponsible Speculation" as a potential name for the proposed chatroom to discuss these questions.

Comment: Hi @casey, thank you for your help, I think the chatroom name is an accurate representation of the general intent of my initial query. I approve.

Comment: The data query is good, some of the answers that come up are definitely relevant. Maybe if we add another condition for "minimum number of comments in thread" it will help select the ones that truly deserve a discussion. Ultimately, the purpose is not to create a space devoid of chat activity. So initially there may only be 1 or 2 questions that fall in this category but as the site grows I think it can provide a good platform for healthy but "Irresponsible Speculation". (maybe that should be the name: "Healthy Irresponsible Speculation" HIS)